# How to add child view controller's view over the parent view

Tags: ios, autolayout

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    ChildViewController *childviewcontroller = [[ChildViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChildViewController" bundle:nil];


    [self addChildViewController:childviewcontroller];
    [self.view addSubview:childviewcontroller.view];
    [childviewcontroller willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    UIView *cview = [[UIView alloc] init];
    cview = childviewcontroller.view;
    [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];

    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(cview);
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint 
                                constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[cview]-|" 
                                                    options:0 metrics:nil                                        
                                                    views:viewsDictionary]];

}
```

I want to add childviewcontroller view over parent view. After adding I set the constraint but it is not working for me.

I am also getting warnings like this

```
2013-07-25 10:47:30.564 neenah[1105:c07] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't 
    understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView 
    property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9256c90 H:|-(NSSpace(20))-[UIView:0x9256a00]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x92557a0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x755d690 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x9256a00(320)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x755d5a0 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x9256a00.midX == + 160>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9256c90 H:|-(NSSpace(20))-[UIView:0x9256a00]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x92557a0 )>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2013-07-25 10:47:30.567 neenah[1105:c07] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9256bb0 H:[UIView:0x9256a00]-(NSSpace(20))-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x92557a0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7561690 h=--- v=--- H:[UIWindow:0x92527c0(320)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x755fe50 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0x92557a0.width == UIWindow:0x92527c0.width>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x755d690 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x9256a00(320)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x755d5a0 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x9256a00.midX == + 160>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9256bb0 H:[UIView:0x9256a00]-(NSSpace(20))-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x92557a0 )>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: You just need this line for that [self.view addSubview:childviewcontroller.view];

Comment: i did it in my second line ,my problem is that my constraint is not working here. @Puneet

Comment: @DhiyanesKaeYes If you're going to use autolayout for this, (a) you're missing the @"V:|-[cview]-|" set of constraints; and (b) you probably would want to `cview.translatesAutosizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO`.

Comment: addChildViewController is used in iOS5 to do viewController containment, this will enable you to easily create your own NavigationCotrollers or TabControllers its only available in iOS5. Do you need any such thing? If No. Then remove this line.

Comment: which line i have to remove @Puneet

Comment: @Puneet No, given that he's adding a view belonging to a child view controller as a subview of the current controller's view, he _absolutely should keep_ the custom container calls of `addChildViewController` and `didMoveToParentViewController` calls. If he's going to support iOS versions prior to 5.0, then fine, put in runtime checks to only call those method when running on iOS 5 (and later). But clearly he's using auto layout, which is iOS 6 and above, so he should do the containment calls.

Comment: Yes Rob you are absolutely right. My bad, I got confused. Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A few observations:

1. You should turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`:

   ```
   childviewcontroller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
   ```
2. You should define vertical constraints, too:

   ```
   [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[cview]-|" 
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:nil                                        
                                                                       views:viewsDictionary]];
   ```
3. Unrelated to your problem, you don't need to create the `[[UIView alloc] init]` for `cview`. You're immediately discarding it.
4. I'm not sure why you're removing the constraints for `self.view`. (I'm presuming you did that as you were tearing your hair out in your testing.) You don't have to do that. But if you have something else going on here that made you think you needed to do that, let us know what that is.
5. When adding a child controller, you call `didMoveToParentViewController`, not `willMoveToParentViewController`. The `addChildViewController` calls `willMoveToParentViewController` for you. You only need the `didMove...` rendition.

Thus:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // instantiate the view controller

    ChildViewController *childViewController = [[ChildViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChildViewController" bundle:nil];

    // or you can instantiate using storyboard
    //
    // ChildViewController *child = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChildIdentifier"];

    // now do the view controller containment calls to update the view controller hierarchy and add the view as appropriate

    [self addChildViewController:childViewController];
    childViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:childViewController.view];
    [childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    UIView *childView = childViewController.view;

    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(childView);
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[childView]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[childView]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
}
```

Comment: thanks for yur response and now only i am learning this concepts thats why i am in trouble. @Rob

Comment: that's worked for me when I loaded the view controller with nib file as here. but when it was from the storyboard. instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier it didn't work. the child container didn't response to the constraints neither the parent view!

Comment: @hasan83 - When you use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`, the process is identical. I just tested it and it works fine. I'd wager that you have some constraints that are not defined properly. If you're still not finding the source of your problem, post your own question with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Comment: Since its the I would I have different contraints man. Wht I noticed that the child controller in the storyboard takes the device screen size and refuses to apply constraints!

Comment: @hasan83 Again, (a) this is not true because constraints works fine when defined properly, but (b) we're not going to diagnose what's wrong with your constraints by continuing to posting short comments here. You should post you own question with a reproducible example of the behavior you're describing. But I used the code above with `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`, and it worked gloriously.

Comment: I used a nib file and it worked thanks for ur answer. Dont the solution for the storyboard controller.

Comment: I solved my problem by using a nib file. But, isn't it possible that the other solution worked for u because u are adding the child view to parent controller view(full sized) which both controller have the same size(device screen). I bet that it work for ur case without adding any constraint. If you try to add it an inner smaller view it wont work with the same code.

Comment: No, I added child who was smaller, inset by 50 points all the way around, and the child had a subview that was further unset by another 50 points all the way around.